# A tag for priority

Tags: discussion, tags

I just asked [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/250879/identifying-the-priority-of-style-css-so-i-can-make-a-small-css-file-load-last) about dependencies and priority of a hook.  Although there is a tag for `wp-dependencies`, there is none that refers to the parameter `priority`.  I think this is an important concept, after all it is its own parameter in a number of WP functions.  I think it might be worth it to add the tag.

What do you all think? Should the tag like `wp-priority`, `hook-priority`,  `load-priority`, or something like that be added?

Answer (score 5):

I have three objections:

1. We do have already too many tags named after functions. Each time WordPress renames or deprecates a function, we get into trouble. If we start to name tags after *function arguments* now, we create a very bad precedent. More trouble will follow.
2. The tag name is too vague. Like `order`, the context is missing. Priority of what? It could also mean (and will inevitably be used for) the priority of SQL results or auto-loading algorithms.
3. We have an existing tag `hooks` already. It covers hook priority and should be used for questions about hooks. Every question tagged `priority` in the meaning you intend here should be tagged with `hooks` also. We will just have a slightly more narrow synonym.

TLDR: I don't think we need that tag.

Comment: I'm not saying the term "priority" needs to be used, but the concept, regarding order of loading is important. It is the concept I think might merit a tag, is there a better term that you would prefer?

Comment: @CoderScissorhands Even `hook-order` would fall under 3.

Comment: I don't understand, `hook-order` doesn't exist, are you suggesting that someone create the tag `hook-order`?

Comment: @CoderScissorhands No, I am suggesting to use the existing tag `hooks` if you have a question about hook priority.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. I hope this gets more responses, I think differently from you, and I am interested in seeing what others think.

Comment: @CoderScissorhands the consensus is that we already have too many tags and that _toscho_ is correct on this one: Please do not add additional tags and if you do, please make the effort to re-tag all 50k+ existing questions.